# How to Get Value in Result View C#?

Tags: c#, object, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to get value in my object. When I look my inside of object, I can see my value in **Result View IEnumerable.** But, I can't get this values.

[image]

When I write **"value."**; just see **"ToString, GetType, GetHashCode and Equals".** I try GetType and get value but I can't. Because, I haven't name of values. How solve we this problem?

Comment: A [mcve] would be great.

Comment: If value always is a `IEnumerable<int>`, change the parameter type correspondingly, i.e. change `object value` to `IEnumerable<int> value` .

Comment: Object is a generic type, you'll either have to declare your method to accept what the object actually is or cast it as the correct type inside your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IEnumerable uses syntactic sugar in the background. IEnumerable I feels like a list but behaves differently. The bigest different is that IEnumerable is lazy evaulated. This means only the requested object will be loaded into the memory. The interface hase a CurrentItem property that is accessed by foreach loop.

Here are some options to access the underlaying value:

1. User foreach

```
foreach (var value in myEnumerableCollection)
{  
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

2. Use LINQ

```
var value = myEnumerableCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x == someSearchTerm);
```

3. Cast the enumartion to a list and use the list methods and use indexers or other list methods to grab the value. A small warning, this will force the collection load every element into the memory. If it is large this may cause some issues. For example loading x million rows of db table with no pagination.

```
int index = 1;
var value = myEnumerableCollection.ToList()[index];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your **value** to IEnumerable T, where T - is your type, for example:

```
   if (value is IEnumerable<int> resultList)
   {
       foreach (int item in resultList)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(item);
       }
   };
```

Comment: It's working. I don't know this loop for cast. Thank you.